# Как написать такой цикл, не внедряя html в php

Tags: php, html, дерево

```
private function buildHTML($productCategories)
{

    $html = '<ul class="dd-list">';

    foreach ($productCategories as $item) {
        $html .= '<li>';
            $html .= $item->title;
            if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) {
                $html .= $this->buildHTML($item->children);
            }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Собираете массив с данными в php. Далее в представлении эти данные выводите в список `ul`. Почитайте про `mvc`

Comment: написать цикл с php в html

Comment: Шаблонизаторы - это ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: Дочерние элементы добавляются динамично
$this->builHTML($item->children);

Comment: В таких целях, делают открытие `html` файла через `php` и заменяют теги или блоки рекурсивно.

Comment: как это сделать ? можно  пример ?

Comment: Почитайте про любые шаблонизаторы - от старенького smarty и заканчивая современным blade.

Comment: Я знаю, о чем вы.
пишу на laravel, но дело в том, что метод buildHTML() 
может быть вызван 'динамично' кол.во раза.
как это написать на blade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-category-treeview-hierarchical-structure-example-with-demoexample.html Вот решение.
Спасибо всем. Мне нужно было сделать так.